# original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 postgresql

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I'm new to development and ran into a problem when deploying the Node.js server side of my application.

I'm developing an online store PERN, locally everything works fine and the application connects to postgresql, but when deployed to 'render' hosting I get an error
original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

```
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect \[as oncomplete\] (net.js:1146:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 5432
}
```

in postgresql.conf I specified port=7440 and listen_addresses = '*'

database connection:

```
export default new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_NAME,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectModule: pg,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST, //127.0.0.1
    port: process.env.DB_PORT, //7440
  }
);
```

postgresql services is running

netstat :

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I'm confused and can't figure out how to fix it. I tried changing the port in postgresql.conf to 5432, but then the application stops working on the local host and an error appears locally:

```
 original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7440
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 7440
  }
```

Any help please

Comment: If your 'render' host is remote I don't see how `127.0.0.1:5432` would work as that is connecting to `localhost`. You will need to provide more information about where your servers are located on the network.

Comment: I believe all your questions will be answered by following this render doc: https://render.com/docs/databases . Just make sure the ```DB_HOST ``` you are passing to your application ```env variables``` match the ```Hostname``` provided by render in their application console for the database.

Comment: thank you, this helped, I specified the hostname of the database instance in the .env file and lo and behold, everything works